# Saml2.0 and data requested by Service Provider

Tags: saml-2.0

Until now i've used openid-connect and now would like to understand how saml works.

I'm not sure how and where SAML Assertion are defined. I know that these are part of the response of the Idp. But is it possible for a ServiceProvider to reqeust specific data (like claims via oidc) of a user?

Let's say a user has an id, firstname, lastname and email.
Is it possible for the service provider just to request a subset of these information? Or are these claims defined on the Idp and maybe even limited  for each service provider?
The worst case i can think about would be that an Idp returns always all information of an user to a service provider...

Answer (score 1):

Typically these are configured on the IDP.

In ADFS e.g. they are defined by claims rules on the IDP.

In SAML there is a "special" claim called NameID which is mandatory.

Essentially it acts as a primary key mapping two systems together.

Comment: tyvm, that helped me a lot to better understand saml :D!